# How to write sql query statement to find the maximum value of certain column in time series of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, max, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When monitoring power consumption, I often need to find the peak load. I would like to know how to write sql to find the maximum value of a certain column in Apache IoTDB. I tried

> SELECT MAX_VALUE(s02), s03, s01 FROM root.s1899.s119.s001

, but it seems like to be wrong and cannot return results. I want to find the time series that has the maximum value of s02, and apply it to s01 and s03. Anyone know how should I write the query statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Apache IoTDB, you can use two sql statements to get your result.

Use `select MAX_VALUE(s02) FROM root.s1899.s119.s001` to get the maximum value of s02, assuming it is recorded as X.

Then use select `s02, s03, s01 from root.s1899. s119.s001 where s02 = X` to find the whole time series.